# Combining string with variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am very new to SQL Server. I want to combine `01-JUL-` and a variable with a year to get a date and am doing this:

```
select 
   *, 
   '01-Jan-1900' as from_date_x, 
   '01-JUL-' + from_finyr as to_date_x
into 
   bbt_item_6_a
from 
   bbt_item_5_finyrs
```

and am getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '01-JUL-' to data type int.

I have tried searching for the answer but cannot get it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the from_finyr field has int data type.  Instead, you need:

```
    select *, 
        '01-Jan-1900' as from_date_x, 
        '01-JUL-' + CAST(from_finyr AS varchar(4)) as to_date_x 
    into bbt_item_6_a 
    from bbt_item_5_finyrs
```

Answer (score 0):

Following SQL is an example, on how you can combine "01-JUL-" and a variable with a year to get a date: SELECT CAST('01-JUL-' + @varaible AS DATE) AS to_date_x